# why Locale.class.isAssignableFrom([locale type].getClass()) returns false?

Tags: java, reflection, types

On java reflection [tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html), the example has this snippet

```
if ((pType.length != 1) || 
    Locale.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass())) { 
  continue; 
}
```

> *"Also, Class.isAssignableFrom() is used to determine whether the parameters of the located  method are compatible with the desired invocation."*

I thought the snippet was trying to find the method with Locale as the parameter.  However, it's trying to look for Locale.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass()) and skip.  The funny thing is that the example works as described because Locale.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass()) returns false when pType[0] is Locale.

Does anybody know why would Locale.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass()) return false when pType[0] is Locale, and what is the proper way to check if the parameter for the method is Locale?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the example is flawed.  The call to `Locale.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass())` is returning false because `Type.getClass()` is returning `Class` and not `Locale`.  This means that the if-statement will never be true since Type's `getClass()` method always seems to return `Class`.

If you add a new method to the class like this:

```
private boolean testBar2(int l) { return true; }
```

this will cause the program to throw an IllegalArgumentException because it will call testBar2 even though the type is not Locale.

`Type` is an interface and calling `pType[0].getClass()` is asking to get the class of `pType[0]`, which is `Class` (not `Locale`) because `Class` implements the `Type` interface. To find out what class the `Type` object represent we can only use its `toString` method and see if it is "class java.util.Locale" because there are no Type-specific methods in the interface.

In short, I think their use of `isAssignableFrom` seems invalid here, and thus their discussion about its use is wrong also.

Comment: But the fact that pType[0] is printing out class java.util.Locale, doesn't that mean pType[0] is referencing a Locale object?  I am just not quite sure why would .getClass() on a Locale object return java.lang.Class.

Comment: It references one, but it "isn't" one.  getClass tells you the class of the object, not what it references.

Comment: I am still not very sure how this works.  Locale.US.getClass() returns java.util.Locale.  Then I assigned Locale.US.getClass() to Type t, and t prints out java.util.Locale.  However, when i printed out t.getClass(), it's java.lang.Class.  When I call t.getClass(), wouldn't it be equivalent to Locale.class, which is Locale?

Comment: The type of `Locale.US` is `Locale`.  The type of `t` is `Type` regardless of what `t` describes. So `t.getClass` will tell you what class it _is_, not which type it _describes_ which is `Class` because that is implementing the `Type` interface.  Another way to think of it is that `t` is not a `Locale` object.  You cannot call `Locale` methods like `getCountry()` on it because it's not an actual `Locale` instance. If it's not a real `Locale` then calling `getClass()` won't say that it is.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  I went back to the example and look at how the check for return type was done so I modified the check for isAssignableFrom to Locale.class == pType[0].  The check does return true when pType[0] is a Locale.  Is this a right way for checking the type of parameters?

Comment: @user3520211 That seems right to me.  The only difference from the original intent is that it would compare false for a subclass of Locale since it only matches something that is exactly a Locale, but I think that's the best you can do with the data. It would be nicer if the `Type` class had a method called `getTypeClass()` that would do what we hoped `getClass()` would do.

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe right:

`if ((pType.length != 1) || !Locale.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) pType[0])) {
    continue;
}`